# Div with "max-width" not reducing its size when the windows is resized

Tags: html, css, position, size

I have a div with "max-width" set to 400px, but when I reduce the size of the windows, it doesn't get smaller to adapt to the new size.

You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/d0d4jx6L/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    fixed menu 
</div>

<div class="content">
    content (displayed on the right of the menu)
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
.menu {
    width:250px;
    position:fixed;
}

.content {
    position:relative;
    left:250px; 
    max-width:400px; /* not working */
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: or like this if you want a marging left : https://jsfiddle.net/d0d4jx6L/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin-left` instead of `left`.

```
.content {
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:250px; /*use instead of left*/
    max-width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you should set to `position:absolute` the `.content`. When you use `left` in css, the element should be `absolute` or `fixe`.

```
.content {
    position:absolute;
    left:250px; 
    max-width:400px; /* not working */
}
```

Here it works 
https://jsfiddle.net/d0d4jx6L/2/